# Android Page curl effect for arabic

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, swipe

I'm working on a project in which i want to swipe Arabic pages using the **curl effect** [harism](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl)

I also tried [harism modify left to right](http://dream-fighter.blogspot.com/2012/10/curl-page-harism-modify-left-to-right.html)  but did not find any help

Answer (score 0):

i have done it just reverse all the pages and set the last position to curlview 
so 37 is the last postilion
mCurlView.setCurrentIndex(37);

Comment: did you really achieve left to right curl? I tried this but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to #Mushtaq Rahim.

Just open `CurlActivity.java` class from ***harism*** provided classes and place your images in reverse order like: img_3,img_2,img_1,
and then change variable `index` size from 0 to your maximum images array size in above case size is 3.